# Using Typeahead in ng2-bootstrap, clicking on a suggestion causes list to close, no selection occurs

Tags: javascript, angular, ng2-bootstrap

Trying to use a TypeAhead input for an Angular2-based web application, specifically a "Tags" input field where you can select multiple tags.

Selecting via keyboard works fine., but I'm running into some problems with selecting via the mouse.  When I click on a previously entered "Tag", the list closes, and my selection isn't updated in the input field.

I've debugged through the browser and determined that a blur event is being sent to the Typeahead component, as a result of me clicking on an option in the drop down, and thus it closes before it can apply the selection.  The blur event seems to be coming from the input itself, and it's trickling down into the typeahead component, causing hide() to be run.

I've tried to suppress the blur event from being passed down (see my stopEvent() method in the code), but that doesn't seem to help, and it still gets run.

Any thoughts on how to approach this would be much appreciated.

Markup:

```
<div class="tags-input" >
  <div class="newtagarea">
<input 
           [(ngModel)]="candidateTag"
           [typeahead]="allTagLabels"
           (typeaheadOnSelect)="addTag($event)"
           [typeaheadOptionField]="'label'"
           (keyup)="inputHandler($event)"
           (blur)="stopEvent($event)"
           [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="5"
           />
  </div> 
</div>
```

TypeScript:

```
import {Component, Input, Output, OnInit, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

import {FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import {TYPEAHEAD_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import {Tag} from '../../model/tag';
import {Errors} from '../../model/errors';
import {TagService} from '../../services/tag.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'tags-input',
  moduleId: module.id,
  styleUrls: ['./tagsinput.css', './tags.css'],
  templateUrl: './tagsinput.html',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, TYPEAHEAD_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [TagService]
})
export class TagsInput implements OnInit {
  @Input() public placeHolderText : string;
  @Output() tagUpdate = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() typeaheadOnSelect  = new EventEmitter();

  private _tags: Tag[];
  private allTags: Tag[];
  private allTagLabels: string[];
  private filteredList: string[];
  private candidateTag: string = '';
  private previousCandidateTag: string = '';
  private tagsInputFocus: boolean = false;
  private currentPlaceHolderText : string;

  constructor(public tagService: TagService) { }

  @Input()
  set tags(t: Tag[]) {
    if (t && t.length > 0) {
      this._tags = t.sort((a: Tag,b: Tag) => {
        if (a.label.toLowerCase() < b.label.toLowerCase()) {
          return -1;
        } else if (a.label.toLowerCase() > b.label.toLowerCase()) {
          return 1;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      });
    } else {
      this._tags = [];
    }
    // always clean up input field
    this.candidateTag = '';
    this.previousCandidateTag = '';
  }

  get tags() {
    return this._tags;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!this.tags) {
      this.tags = [];
    }
    this.loadTags();
  }

  loadTags(onComplete: (result: boolean) => void = null) {
    var me = this;
    this.tagService.getTags().subscribe(
      vals => {
        me.allTags = vals;
        me.allTagLabels = [];
        if (vals) {
          vals.forEach(t => {
            me.allTagLabels.push(t.label);
          });
        }
        if (onComplete) {
          onComplete(true);
        }
      },
    err => {
      // TODO: handle errors
      console.log(err);
      if (onComplete) {
        onComplete(false);
      }
    });
    this.currentPlaceHolderText = this.placeHolderText;
  }

  addTag(event: any): void {
    this.addAndPossiblyCreateTag(event.item);
    this.tagUpdate.emit(this.tags);
  }

  inputHandler(event: any): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ((event.code === 'Enter') || (event.code === 'NumpadEnter')) {
      if (event.currentTarget.nextElementSibling === null) {
        // User has hit enter in the text box, not picked from dropdown
        this.addAndPossiblyCreateTag(event.currentTarget.value);
      }
      event.target.value = '';
    } else if (event.code === 'Backspace') {
      if ((this.previousCandidateTag === '') && (this.candidateTag === '')) {
        this.removeLastEnteredTagAndNotify();
      } else {
        console.log(this.previousCandidateTag);
        this.filterTagLabels();
      }
    } else {
      this.filterTagLabels();
    }
    this.previousCandidateTag = this.candidateTag;
  }

  restoreFocus(el: any): void {
    el.focus();
  }

  removeElement(i: number): void {
    this.tags.splice(i, 1);
    this.candidateTag = '';
    this.tagUpdate.emit(this.tags);
  }

  showTagsInputFocus() {
    this.tagsInputFocus = true;
  }

  stopEvent(event) {
    if (! event) {
      return;
    }
    if (event.preventDefault) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    if (event.stopImmediatePropagation) {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
    if (event.stopPropagation) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }

  hideTagsInputFocus() {
    this.tagsInputFocus = false;
  }

  private addAndPossiblyCreateTag(value: string): void {
    var tag = value.trim();
    if (!tag || tag.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    let me = this;
    if (me.getCurrentTagLabelsLowerCase().indexOf(tag.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
      // given tag is already part of current tags
      this.candidateTag = '';
      return;
    }

    let existingTag: Tag = this.getExistingTag(tag);
    if (!existingTag) {
      // tag does not exist, we need to create it
      let newTag: Tag = new Tag();
      newTag.label = tag;
      this.tagService.createTag(newTag).subscribe(
        (val: Tag) => {
          newTag = val;
          this.allTags.push(newTag);
          this.allTagLabels.push(newTag.label);
          this.addTagAndNotify(newTag);
        },
        (err: Errors) => {
          if (err.validationErrors) {
            // if this is validation error - it means tag already exists - i.e. most likely
            // someone else added it meantime. Need to refresh our tag list..
            this.loadTags((res) => {
              if (res) {
                // try to reload tag and add it
                let existingTag: Tag = this.getExistingTag(tag);
                if (existingTag) {
                  this.addTagAndNotify(existingTag);
                } else {
                  // TODO: not sure if it can happen
                  console.log('Could not create tag [' + tag + ']');
                }
              }
            });
          } else if (err.genericErrors) {
            // TODO: handle generic errors
            console.log(err.genericErrors);
          }
        });
    } else {
      // existing tag, just add it to the asset
      this.addTagAndNotify(existingTag);
    }
  }

  private addTagAndNotify(tag: Tag): void {
    let existingTags: Tag[] = this.tags;
    existingTags.push(tag);
    this.candidateTag = '';
    this.previousCandidateTag = this.candidateTag;
    this.tagUpdate.emit(existingTags);
    this.currentPlaceHolderText = this.placeHolderText;
  }

  private getCurrentTagLabelsLowerCase(): string[] {
    let labels: string[] = [];
    if (this.tags) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.tags.length; i++) {
        labels.push(this.tags[i].label.toLowerCase());
      }
    }
    return labels;
  }

  private getExistingTag(tag: string): Tag {
    if (!this.allTags) { return null; }
    for (var i = 0; i < this.allTags.length; i++) {
      if (this.allTags[i].label.toLowerCase() === tag.toLowerCase()) {
        return this.allTags[i];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  private removeLastEnteredTagAndNotify(): void {
    this.tags.pop();
    this.candidateTag = '';
    this.tagUpdate.emit(this.tags);
  }

  private filterTagLabels() : void {
      this.filteredList = this.allTagLabels.filter(function(el) {
        return this.getCurrentTagLabelsLowerCase().indexOf(el.toLowerCase()) < 0;
      }.bind(this));
  }

}
```

Comment: Found a fix or workaround?